# Pass Class Member to Method Argument

Tags: c++, function, class, member-functions

how can I access class member in the function argument

```
class Array
{
private:
    int size;
public:
    void fill(int start = 0, int end = **size**)
        {
            // Function Body
        }
};
```

I tried to use that

```
public:
    void fill(int start = 0, int end = NULL)
        {
            if (end == NULL)
               end = size;
            // Function Body
        }
```

Comment: Make two overloads of `fill`. One with and one without the `end` parameter. `void fill(int start = 0) { fill(start, size); }`

Comment: That is not possible in C++.  you can use the method @user17732522 proposes but then you do have to remove your default value for end from the constructor with 2 arguments. Side note, do not use `NULL` (a define in a header file with value `0`) in C++ but use `nullptr`

Comment: You could use a magic token value: `void fill(int start = 0, int end = -1) { if (end == -1) end = size; /*rest of body*/ }`

Comment: @PepijnKramer: OP has to use `0` not `nullptr` for `int` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 *doh* you're absolutely right... :)

Comment: @Eljay magic tokens only work by "documentation" and cannot be enforced. Which kind of reminds me to mention that `std::size_t` is a better type to indicate indices into an array. (to prevent negative out-of-bound indices in the first place)

Comment: @PepijnKramer • Agreed on both points.  Could make it more self documenting:  `enum class use_size{};` and `void fill(std::size_t start = 0, std::variant<std::size_t, use_size> end_var = use_size{});`

Comment: @PepijnKramer Sure that tokens cannot be enforced but it is pretty straightforward if the function will just replace any invalid end values with size. For instance that if end is negative or if end > size.

Comment: @stackoverblown these kind of "convenience" or implicit behaviors usually end up in maintenance problems later (documentation gets out of sync, unexpected input is given etc. etc.). Like Eljay shows try to be as explicit as possible when defining functions and their expectations.  Then combine that with unit tests to ensure those contracts will never be broken in the future.

Comment: @Eljay Yes I like that kind of explicitness.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of use cases for your function:

```
Array a;
int start = ...;
int end = ...;
//first case
a.fill(start, end);
//second case
a.fill(start);
//third case;
a.fill();
```

In that case, I would define three methods: One to do the actual job and the other two as the convenience methods:

```
class Array
{
private:
    int size;
public:
//main method
    void fill(int start, int end)
    {
        // Function Body
    }
//convenience methods
    void fill(int start)
    {
        fill(start, size);
    }
    void fill()
    {
        fill(0, size);
    }
};
```

This is not recommended practice for C++, because your class then gets bloated with convenience methods. Imagine if you had more optional parameters per method call, you would have to write one convenience method per optional parameter.

Better solution is to simply remove default values for parameters and use explicit values each time. In the long term your code will not be any bigger and you keep the clarity of this method.

```
class Array
{
private:
    int size;
public:
    int getSize()
        {
            return size;
        }
    void fill(int start, int end)
        {
            // Function Body
        }
};
```

When using your code, you would then just have to write a few extra parameters:

```
int main()
{
    Array a;
    a.fill(0, a.getSize());
    //with default values it would be
    //a.fill();
}
```

If you see the use of no parameters as a particularly often occurrence, then write a single convenience method for it, but I would still argue that the example above is as clean as it needs to be.